# Simple program Reference error

Tags: c++

Hello I'm just starting to comprehend using classes in C++.  Can't seem to get this simple program to work.

I get the **error**:

```
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall functions::add(int,int)" (?add@functions@@QAEHHH@Z) referenced in function _wmain
1>c:\users\brr\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication4\Debug\ConsoleApplication4.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

My code is as follows:

**main.cpp:**

```
// ConsoleApplication4.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "functions.h"
#include <iostream>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    bool running = true;

    while(running)
    {
        functions func;
        int var1, var2;
        int option = 0;
        switch (option)
        {
        case(1):
            std::cin >> var1 >> var2;
            func.add(var1,var2);



        }


    }
    return 0;
}
```

**functions.cpp:**

```
#include "functions.h"
#include <iostream>


functions::functions(void)
{
}


functions::~functions(void)
{
}

int add(int var1,int var2){
    int r;
    r = var1 + var2;
    return r;

}
```

**functions.h:**

```
#pragma once
class functions
{
public:
    functions(void);
    ~functions(void);
    int add(int var1,int var2);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int functions::add(int var1,int var2){
    int r;
    r = var1 + var2;
    return r;

}
```

Implementation in your `functions.cpp` should look like above. In your current implementation `add` is a global function.

So your `functions.cpp` must look like:

```
#include "functions.h"
#include <iostream>


functions::functions(void)
{
}


functions::~functions(void)
{
}

int functions::add(int var1,int var2){
    int r;
    r = var1 + var2;
    return r;

}
```

Comment: @user1068329 kindly accept the answer if you think it was useful :-)

Answer (score 0):

As, your `add` is a global declaration. You can use this in your main.cpp::

```
int Result ;
switch (option)
    {
    case(1):
        std::cin >> var1 >> var2;
        Result = add(var1,var2);
    }
```

Else @Aniket provided you the solution.